# Strange java.util.calendar Output

Tags: java

I am trying to clear the time portion from a Date using Java Calendar. Here is the code based on the other stackoverflow solutions:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// cal.setTime(new Date());
cal.clear(Calendar.HOUR);
cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
// cal.clear(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);
cal.clear(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

But the current output is: `2014-01-20 12:00:00`

What could be the reason? Why the time is showing `12:00:00`? I just want my Date Object with a time `00:00:00`.

Comment: You should use `set(field, 0)` rather than clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per `javadoc` of `Calendar.clear`:

> The HOUR_OF_DAY, HOUR and AM_PM fields are handled independently and
>   the the resolution rule for the time of day is applied. Clearing one
>   of the fields doesn't reset the hour of day value of this Calendar.
>   Use set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0) to reset the hour value.

So instead of `clear` use:

```
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
```

`clear` isn't actually clearing `hour` value, hence so much messing around formatters!

Comment: It was kind of hidden truth inside `Calender`, logically you were attempting the right thing :), accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Yes sure, 8 minutes barrier of stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 4):

The date/calendar is ok, the error is in your format string:

- **hh**: means 12h time format
- **HH**: means 24h time format

Correct format string:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Output:

```
2014-01-20 00:00:00
Mon Jan 20 00:00:00 CET 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```